# How to read a sublist data in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am new to suitescript. Openly telling I hardly wrote two scripts by seeing other scripts which are little bit easy.

My question is how can read a data from sublist and call other form.

Here is my requirement.

[I want to read the item values data highlighted in yellow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iElZp.png)

When I read that particular item in a variable I want to call the assemblyitem form in netsuite and get one value.

```
//Code

function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request)
{

nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'This event is occured while ', type);

    if(type == 'create' || type == 'copy' || type == 'edit')
        {
            var recType = nlapiGetRecordType(); //Gets the RecordType
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recType', recType);

            //
            if(recType == 'itemreceipt')
                {
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'The following form is called ',recType);
                    //var itemfield = nlapiGetFieldValue('item')
                    //nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','This value is = ',itemfield);
                    var formname = nlapiLoadRecord('itemreceipt',itemfield);
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','This value is = ',formname);

                }

        }

}
```

How can I proceed further?

[I want to read that checkbox field value in the following image when i get the item value from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTdKD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried for my end and got succeed. Here is the answer.

function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request){

```
if(type=='copy'|| type =='edit' || type=='create'){

    var recType = nlapiGetRecordType(); //Gets the RecordType
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recType', recType);
    //
    if(recType == 'itemreceipt')
        {
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'The following form is called ',recType);
            var itemcount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','This value is = ',+itemcount);
            for(var i=1;i<=itemcount;i++)
                {
                    var itemvalue = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','itemkey',i);
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','LineItemInternalID = ',itemvalue);
                    var itemrecord = nlapiLoadRecord('assemblyitem', itemvalue);
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','BOM= ',itemrecord);
                    if(itemrecord == null){
                        var itemrecord = nlapiLoadRecord('inventoryitem', itemvalue);
                        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','BOM= ',itemrecord);  
                    }
                    var value = itemrecord.getFieldValue('custitem_mf_approved_for_dock_to_stock');
                    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG',"Checkboxvalue = ",value);
                    if(value == 'F'){

                        nlapiSetLineItemValue('item','location',i,9);
                        nlapiSetLineItemDisabled ('item','location',false,i );
                    }
                    else{
                        nlapiSetLineItemValue('item','location',i,1);
                        nlapiSetLineItemDisabled ('item','location',true,i );

                    }

                }

        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the "Sublist APIs" page in NetSuite's Help; it should describe many of the methods you'll be working with.

In particular you'll want to look at `nlobjRecord.getLineItemValue()`.

Here's a video copmaring how to work with sublists in 1.0 versus 2.0: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n05OiKYDxhI

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and let you know sir.

Comment: I have tried using those api's but it is not working.